# Query from 2 sheets based on the conditions

Tags: google-sheets

I have 2 worksheets in the Google spreadsheet, where i want to take single cell value from the other sheet based on 3 different conditions.

Sheet1:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzqbs.png)

Sheet2:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDQiM.png)

Required output
The Price to be brought in col D,E,F in sheet one need to be filled based on the condition Product, Category, Date and Region based on the Date in the Sheet 2

Thanks in Advance

I tried many if condition's couldn't get off the parsing error